# Failed to bind Ray Serve HTTP proxy to '127.0.0.1:8000'

Tags: python, fastapi, ray

Started Ray Head node with below command :

```
ray start \
       --head \
       --port=6379 \
       --object-manager-port=8076 \
     --include-dashboard=true \
       --dashboard-host=0.0.0.0 \
      --dashboard-port=8266
```

Output:

```
local node IP: localhost
2021-07-10 20:58:01,607 INFO services.py:1245 -- View the Ray dashboard at http://localhost:8266

--------------------
Ray runtime started.
--------------------

Next steps
  To connect to this Ray runtime from another node, run
    ray start --address='localhost:PORT' --redis-password='xxxx'
  
  Alternatively, use the following Python code:
    import ray
    ray.init(address='auto', _redis_password='xxxx')
  
  If connection fails, check your firewall settings and network configuration.
  
  To terminate the Ray runtime, run
    ray stop
```

After this wrote a small python code on fastapi:

```
import ray
from ray import serve

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

serve_handle = None

@app.on_event("startup") # Code to be run when the server starts.
async def startup_event():
    ray.init(address='auto', _redis_password='xxxx')
    client = serve.start()
    for _ in range(100):
        x.append(1)
    print(x)
```

But when i run the scrit with command :

> uvicorn py_code:app

Got below errors:

```
ValueError: Failed to bind Ray Serve HTTP proxy to '127.0.0.1:8000'.
Please make sure your http-host and http-port are specified correctly.
```

Can someone just explain how can i make it work. Thank you

Comment: Where does 127.0.0.1:8000 come from? You are probably not showing the one file we need to see.

Comment: which file you mean @tripleee. Uvicorn actually try to connect to localhost if no port and ip mentioned i think